# VaultSharp: Why I get the "no handler for route" error?

Tags: c#, docker, vault, vaultsharp

Windows 10 x64

Vault works in the docker container on my computer. I can get my secret successfully by the container console:

[image]

But I get the exception when I try to do the same through C# code (VaultSharp, .Net Framework 4.8):

```
try
{
    IAuthMethodInfo authMethod = new TokenAuthMethodInfo("myroot");

    var vaultClientSettings = new VaultClientSettings(
        "http://localhost:8200", authMethod);

    IVaultClient vaultClient = new VaultClient(vaultClientSettings);
    
    Secret<SecretData> kv2Secret = await vaultClient.V1.Secrets.KeyValue.V2
        .ReadSecretAsync(path: "secret/dev/crm", mountPoint: "kv");
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    throw ex; // ERROR: {"errors":["no handler for route 'kv/data/secret/dev/crm'"]}
}
```

Why I get it and how can I solve this problem?

Answer (score -1):

It seems like bug. I found the decission of my problem [here](https://forum.devmentors.io/t/vaultsharp-error/226).